# How to install Basemap, getting errors

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, matplotlib-basemap

Hi guys i am trying to install ( pip install mpl_toolkits ). i get 
**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpl_toolkits (from versions: )**
**No matching distribution found for mpl_toolkits**

have installed geos, matplotlib, pyproj. do i need to install any other dependencies.

Also tried running, **pip install Desktop/basemap-1.2.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl**

getting error: basemap-1.2.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Havent had problems installing any libraries. Can someone throw light as to what needs to be done in this case.

P.S i am running Python 3.7.3 version

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i got from another stack question resolution:

```
import mpl_toolkits
mpl_toolkits.__path__.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

My version is 3.7 but if i use the above I am able to vizualise a map